# Why doesn't Cox encrypt my password?

Tags: password-management

Cox does not encrypt my WiFi password on my account page. So anyone working for Cox has access to my WiFi password. How can I secure my WiFi password?

Comment: It would mean that someone from Cox would have to be physically close to your home to do anything with that information. Why would you want to encrypt your wifi password? What do you want to protect against?

Comment: Why would use use a vendor-provided WiFi anyway? Scary. hotspots are pretty cheap these days...